# SQL: Modelling template inheritance

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

I wanted to ask whether it is possible to model a templated datastructure which can be overriden if necessary.

Suppose we have a list with the following items:

**Template List**

- Item 1 Position 0
- Item 2 Position 1
- Item 3 Position 2
- Item 4 Position 3

Now I want to create a list which uses *Template List* as a base, but modifies some parts of it:

**Concrete List, based on Template List**

- Item 1 Position 0 // Inherited from Template List
- Item 5 Position 1 // New and only available in Concrete List
- Item 4 Position 2 // Inherited from Template List, but with a different position
- Item 3 Position 3 // Inherited from Template List, but with a different position

In this list *Item 2* from Template List is missing should not be a part of the resulting list.

Is it possible to model these relations in SQL? (We are using PostgreSQL)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do something like what you want, but it's not necessarily a good solution or what you need. What you're asking for looks like a metamodel, but relational databases were designed for first-order logical models, and while SQL can go beyond that somewhat, it's usually better not to go too abstract.

That said, here's an example. I assumed the identity of list items were position or slot-based.

```
CREATE TABLE template_list (
    template_list_id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (template_list_id)
);

CREATE TABLE template_list_items (
    template_list_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    slot_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    item_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (template_list_id, slot_number),
    FOREIGN KEY (template_list_id) REFERENCES template_list (template_list_id)
);

CREATE TABLE concrete_list (
    concrete_list_id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    template_list_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (template_list_id) REFERENCES template_list (template_list_id),
    UNIQUE (concrete_list_id, template_list_id)
);

CREATE TABLE concrete_list_items (
    concrete_list_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    template_list_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    slot_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    item_number INTEGER NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (concrete_list_id, slot_number),
    FOREIGN KEY (concrete_list_id, template_list_id) REFERENCES concrete_list (concrete_list_id, template_list_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (template_list_id, slot_number) REFERENCES template_list_items (template_list_id, slot_number)
);
```

Now, to get the items in a concrete list, you would use a query like:

```
SELECT c.concrete_list_id, x.slot_number, x.item_number
FROM concrete_list c
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ci.concrete_list_id,
         COALESCE(ci.template_list_id, ti.template_list_id) AS template_list_id,
         COALESCE(ci.slot_number, ti.slot_number) AS slot_number,
         COALESCE(ci.item_number, ti.item_number) AS item_number
  FROM concrete_list_items AS ci
  FULL JOIN template_list_items AS ti ON ci.template_list_id = ti.template_list_id
                                     AND ci.slot_number = ti.slot_number
) x ON c.concrete_list_id = x.concrete_list_id OR c.template_list_id = x.template_list_id;
```

Here's a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e2170/14) for demonstration. Note that I replaced the serial types with integers and hardcoded values for simplicity of demonstration.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer! I'll keep the metamodel in the application logic then.